# Using an rxjs Observable with firestore

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an rxjs observable on the Query#onSnapshot method.  This is my code:

```js
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(db.collection('conversations')
     .where('members.' + auth.currentUser.uid, '==', true).onSnapshot)
observable.subscribe({next(value){console.log('value', value)}})
```

The error I receive is this:

TypeError: this.onSnapshotInternal is not a function

It seems that the onSnapshot method is set to be duck-typed as an observable.
Firestore doesn't have enough documentation yet for me to figure this out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you pass `onSnapshot` to `Rx.Observable.create`, you are passing it unbound to a query. That is, you are just passing the `Query.prototype.onSnapshot` function.

You could either use `bind`, like this:

```js
const query = db
  .collection('conversations')
  .where('members.' + auth.currentUser.uid, '==', true);
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(query.onSnapshot.bind(query));
observable.subscribe({
  next(value) { console.log('value', value); }
});
```

Or could use an arrow function, like this:

```js
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => db
  .collection('conversations')
  .where('members.' + auth.currentUser.uid, '==', true)
  .onSnapshot(observer)
);
observable.subscribe({
  next(value) { console.log('value', value); }
});
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.